# This code throws an error at line 6. Is it because cout stream doesn't allow it or it's some conflict in ostream?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cout

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int a=4,b;
   cout<<b=a*a;
   return 0;
}
```

it shows

```
"error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'char')"
```

If it has to do something with cout, can someone tell me how does cin and cout works exactly?

Comment: please include the error message in the quesiton, it should tell you already whats wrong with the code. If you cannot understand it, no problem, others can help you with that, but reading the error message is the first step

Comment: Try this:  `int a=4; int b=a*a;  cout <<b<< endl;`  The problem is that you're inadvertently jumbling declaration, definition, assignment and operator overloading all together :(  The solution is to simplify your code by breaking things out into separate statements.

Comment: i don't think the error is from that code. I'd rather expect "(operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'int')"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here for operator precedence: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence.

`<<` has rank 7. `=` has rank 16. And `*` has rank 5. Hence the line is parsed as

```
(std::cout << b ) = (a * a);
```

You cannot assign an `int` to `std::cout`. Write this instead:

```
int a = 4;
int b = a*a;
std::cout << b;
```